# Newbie Django: Creating a project with several apps or all in one

Tags: python, django

I am begginer in the Django world, I developed some "information sites" (nothing complicated) but this week my boss order me to make a migration of a big software that has 7 modules.

So I went to read the documentation page and search in google for how I could design this software using Django. I know that the every "module" can named as "app", so I create a new project and one app for every module (I dont know if it was right because the modules will not be public).

The problem is that now I don't know what is the next step.

All my apps can share data (every app has its owns models but sometimes one app has a model that was related to the models in other apps)?

Where  do I write the code for the login process (I create a manageUsers app that was thinked to handle the registration, edit, share and validate profile of the current or new user ) and we can be able to share this session data accross the apps?

I need one more app for put the website information (like contact, about, pricing ...)?  I use Python 2.7, Django 1.3, Memcached and Mysql 5.

If someone can help me or tell me where it may clarify these questions because most explains how to develop using only one app and in the IRC got no reply or else I must be write all the code in one app?

Best Regards

Comment: Hi, I have this project in my office because I'm the only one who has had "contact" with django plus the rest of the team continues to maintain the current version (PHP & Perl). As I have a beta version I can use a couple of developers to help me. The question is where to start because I can not find any guide or example to begin development using many apps.

Comment: Definitely look at the Django Book (version 2.0) I linked to in the answer. If you read chapters 1-10 sequentially, it'll walk you through enough to get the ball rolling.

Comment: Well you're doing good - utilizing the web. But if you're in an office, it's much harder to get away with research as "work", though it does save you lots of time later on. Im open to test a beta if you ever need help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A good place to start (dated, but worth reading; look at user comment bubbles too): http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/ . Chapter 1 - 10 are essential reading. You can pick-and-choose to read the remaining chapters, if desired.

Yes, all Django Apps can share data with one another. You make multiple Django Application's, housed under a single Django Project. The Project sets up a common database to use, and each Application creates Models which use said database. App1 can talk to App2 and vice-versa.

```
Django Project (one)  <----->>  (many) Django Application
```

Typically you separate Apps based on common function. User accounts get their own app (see Auth below). Blog postings get another. A Google Maps interface will get another. User subscriptions, another.

For user accounts and login, Django provides the [Auth Module](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/auth/). You can have user accounts stored directly in Django, or configure it to talk to something else, like Active Directory. Auth works "pretty good" out of the box, though I personally customized mine a bit to allow 255-character email addresses as usernames (by default, it limits to 40 characters). [Chapter 14](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter14/) in the Django book might be a little easier to read than the official Auth docs. If you do use Auth, you don't have to make your own Django Application, since Auth already is one! You just install it in settings.py and you're golden.

Your Django structure will likely look something like this:

```
/Project/
  __init__.py
  manage.py
  settings.py
  urls.py

  App1/
    __init__.py
    forms.py
    models.py
    views.py
    templates/App1/
      template1.html
      template2.html

  App2/
    ...
```

App2 can access the data-models of App1 by doing: `from Project.App1.models import someModel`

Comment: +1 for `auth`, also, there's sign in options for openID and certain kinds of emails out there that you can drop in with a good package manager. Maybe there's one for facebook, or google+?

Comment: Ok suppose I use the Auth module in App1 to create the login and registration, then the App2 can use the data once they loggin at the App1? Thanks for the django book ;) +1000

Comment: Auth itself is an app. After you install Auth in settings.py, you typically apply the login_required() decorator to view functions you want a user to be logged-in to access. login_required() can be used on "any" view function in "any" App. If a user access it, and isn't logged in, login_required() re-directs them to a login page. After logging in, they're re-directed back to the view function. Optionally, you can attach a "profile" to an Auth user, which lets you apply custom data to a user account (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/auth/#storing-additional-information-about-users)

Comment: Continuing with my comment, if you want to attach a Profile to an Auth User, you typically create a "light" Django Application just for this purpose. You might name it "profile" and create a Profile() in its models.py. You probably won't do anything in its forms.py or views.py files. You can access said profile using the User from Auth, via `profile = some_user.get_profile()`. Auth doesn't let you add extra data to a User, except through this method of creating a separate "Profile" Django Application, and linking the two.

Answer (score 3):

For me, rules are simple.

1. If you need to copy-paste some code from one project to another - make an app for it
2. If one of app's modules code is bigger than 1k lines and/or hard to maintain - look for something to move in separate app
3. Group functionality into apps to minimize cross-linking between them

For interconnection you can use [signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/signals/) and [sessions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/sessions/)